# Run unit test with robolectric get Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, robolectric

The offical demo can't run correctly. When I run the unit test demo, it show android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050000 in the consle.

As the reason of network , I can't use m2e to create my project. But I download all the needed .jar with maven on another computer and copy the to this one, then add them into Eclipse IDE Java Build Path --> Library

And here is my source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View button = findViewById(R.id.login);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and the test code are as follow:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
  @Test
  public void onCreateShouldInflateTheMenu() {
  Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

  final Menu menu = shadowOf(activity).getOptionsMenu();
  assertEquals("First menu item", menu.findItem(R.id.item1).getTitle());
  assertEquals("Second menu item", menu.findItem(R.id.item2).getTitle());
}
```

When I run the testcase with junit test, they following error info are shows in the "failure trace":

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050000
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:400)
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:409)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.getActivityTitle(ActivityController.java:113)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:61)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.of(ActivityController.java:32)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:92)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:88)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:96)
at com.example.activity.MainActivityTest.clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity(MainActivityTest.java:35)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:467)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:176)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:142)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I also tried to override the RobolectricTestRunner and add the *@Config* tag, but it's the same result.
How can I fix the problem and run the demo successfully?

Comment: By the way the Robolectric is 3.1.2 and android 6.0

Comment: What is `MyRunner` and how layout of activity looks like?

Comment: Here is the code of MyRunner

Comment: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2653  , and the layout of activity is the just like http://robolectric.org/writing-a-test/

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must be add testOptions { unitTests { includeAndroidResources = true } } to android on build.gradle module configuration

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests { includeAndroidResources = true }
    }
}
```